# How to filter by a very large list of URLs with the Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have Node.js code which looks a bit like this:

```
analytics.data.ga.get({
  metrics: 'ga:pageviews,ga:users',
  dimensions: 'ga:date',
  filters: urlPaths.map(path => `ga:pagePath==${path}`).join(','),
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
  // sort: '-ga:date',
  'max-results': 30,
}, (err, response) => {
  if (err) return next(err)
  res.json(response)
})
```

Where urlPaths can potentially a be a very large array.

To give some context, I have a website where each users can upload images which end up having their own unique url (e.g. `/file/:some_unique_hash`) and I'd like to be able to filter out my analytics data per user. The only way to do that right now is to pull out the list of file a user has uploaded and pass a potentially very large URL list to the filter parameter of the Google Analytics API.

It would be a lot easier if each URL were prefixed by the user's username (e.g. `/:some_username/:some_file`) as that would allow me to simply pass a regex to the filter. But unfortunately, I don't think I'll be able to change the URL structure.

I believe one solution would be to pass additional data to GA using their client side script to "tag" certain page views as "belonging" to a user and then use that custom variable to filter out GA data. Is that possible? Other suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: "urlPaths can potentially a be a very large array"  not really because you are limited to how long of a string filters will take I think the max length if memory serves is 2000.

Comment: I think the option would be to add a custom dimension when you insert the data to google analytics and then filter on the custom dimension.

Comment: "not really because you are limited to how long of a string filters will take" Yes which is the problem... "add a custom dimension when you insert the data to google analytics" which was my suggested solution. Do you have sample code or a documentation reference for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating an "author" custom dimension in Google Analytics and setting that dimension on all my `/file/...` page views. I can then filter by the author dimension when retrieving data using the Google Analytics Core API. Here's a link that helped: http://www.vsellis.com/add-author-tracking-google-analytics-wordpress-website/

Comment: Useful tip, but this is a way to label the hits via JS, not to upload a list of URLs.